# Is it possible to refresh 3rd party widgets?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm writing an application that changes the screen brightness.  I also use a 3rd party widget that both changes the screen brightness and displays the current brightness value.  My program and the 3rd party widget have different functions and I want to continue to use them both.  However, when my application changes the screen brightness, the 3rd party widget doesn't automatically refresh to reflect this change.  So, my questions are:

- Is it possible for my application to call the 3rd party widget to be refreshed?
- If so, is this done by refreshing every widget on the phone, or can I target that specific widget (by package name, for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for my application to call the 3rd party widget to be refreshed?

Not readily, and quite possibly not at all.

> If so, is this done by refreshing every widget on the phone

AFAIK, that is not possible.

> or can I target that specific widget (by package name, for example)?

You would have no choice in the matter.

The only way that this might work is if you call `sendBroadcast()` with the same `Intent` that the system would use for updating the third-party app widget. You would need to specify the `ComponentName` of the other app's `AppWidgetProvider`. And, you have no way of knowing what the app widget IDs are for that particular `Intent` extra. If the third-party `AppWidgetProvider` is expecting something in this broadcast (e.g., app widget IDs) that you are not providing, it will likely crash. It's also possible that this broadcast is secured and cannot be sent by other apps -- I've never tried this.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like what I suspected.  Thought it was worth asking, though.  Thanks!